# How to model multiple windows in a building walls?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am currently going to model a building from a reference

[image]

The image i found.
I have an idea on how to go about modeling it but what I'm looking for is some help on what would be the best way to go about creating the windows as in this image. The windows go right along and down the building.

Comment: you should model the window, then use an Array modifier to repeat it horizontally and vertically, is it the kind of trick you're looking for?

Comment: im looking so that the window looks like it is part of the building and when i add a glass texture i want it so that i can be able to see through , wont it just show the building through the glass if i model it separate and attach it ?  novice question i know

Comment: You need to cut windows through the walls obviously, if wall doesn't have any hole window will be just attached to the wall. I'd suggest looking at some tutorials on modeling buildings, e.g https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qJJRC2ebvSE